# How do you create a sum of integer values saved in different tables in sqlite database in android studio?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have 2 tables in my sqlite database as you will see below and I am allowing the user to enter values into both tables. How would I add the amounts saved in each table. Then I would like to take away one of the sum values from the other. Also I would like to show it in a fragment where it shows the totals of both tables and then it shows the final value of one of the sum values taken away from the other.

Here is my database helper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "budget.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "expense_table";
public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "income_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "_id";
public static final String COL_2 = "_id";
public static final String EXPENSE_AMOUNT = "AMOUNT";
public static final String EXPENSE_DATE = "DATE";
public static final String EXPENSE_NOTES = "NOTES";
public static final String INCOME_AMOUNT = "AMOUNT";
public static final String INCOME_DATE = "DATE";
public static final String INCOME_NOTES = "NOTES";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 3);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, AMOUNT INTEGER,DATE INTEGER,NOTES TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,AMOUNT INTEGER,DATE INTEGER,NOTES TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME2);
    onCreate(db);}

public boolean insertexpenseData(String amount_expense, String date_expense, String notes_expense) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(EXPENSE_AMOUNT, amount_expense);
    contentValues.put(EXPENSE_DATE, date_expense);
    contentValues.put(EXPENSE_NOTES, notes_expense);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public boolean insertincomeData(String amount_income, String date_income, String notes_income) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(INCOME_AMOUNT, amount_income);
    contentValues.put(INCOME_DATE, date_income);
    contentValues.put(INCOME_NOTES, notes_income);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getexpenseData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor getincomeData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME2, null);
    return res;
}


public boolean updateexpenseData(String id, String amount, String date, String notes) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
    contentValues.put(EXPENSE_AMOUNT, amount);
    contentValues.put(EXPENSE_DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(EXPENSE_NOTES, notes);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
    return true;
}

public boolean updateincomeData(String id, String amount, String date, String notes) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, id);
    contentValues.put(INCOME_AMOUNT, amount);
    contentValues.put(INCOME_DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(INCOME_NOTES, notes);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME2, contentValues, "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteexpenseData(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
    }

public Integer deleteincomeData(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME2, "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
}


}
```

Please let me know if you need anything else from my code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking for. The sum of all income amounts minus the sum of all expenses? That would be two simple SELECT SUM(column)

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I mean how would I take away the sum of one of the table of one of the tables from the sum of the other table.

Comment: With sum, do you mean everything in that table, or a specific subset? Would this query work out for you? SELECT SUM(amount) - (SELECT sum(amount) FROM expense_table) FROM income_table

Comment: Not everything in the table, I only want to add up the amounts nothing else from each table

Comment: Yes, I was more concerned about a specific timeframe. What this query does is summing up all the amount values in your income table and subtracting the sum of all the amount values in the expense table. Lets say income amounts are 1000,2000,3000 expense amounts are 1000,1000 it returns 4000

Comment: Yeah exactly, I'm sorry if I was not explaining it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, that comes down to a single SQL query to your database.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT SUM(amount) - (SELECT sum(amount) FROM expense_table) FROM income_table";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int yourDesiredValue = cursor.getInt(0);
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: I get cannot resolve method when I try to use rawQuery

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, couldnt remember the api out of my head. Add a null parameter to the method. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I still get the same error, do I have to create rawQuery in my database handler

Comment: Look at your methods like getexpenseData. You'll need to create a method like these. but instead of returning a Cursor, you will return the integer value from cursor.getInt(0)

Comment: So what should I write in the database helper, I am fairly new to sqlite programming

Comment: https://pastebin.com/836gKq66 this method should be located in your DatabaseHelper. It's like the other methods you have already

Comment: What should I put in my main activity fragment to show the final value that is worked out in the database helper

Comment: That depends on what you have there. But some sort of TextView in it, get a reference to that in your onCreate method via findViewById(R.id.your_label). Thats really basic android though, Please consult any android tutorial for that

Comment: I know how to do that but I get a null object reference even though I have referenced it in my xml file

Comment: Then you have done something wrong. Hard to say without code to see, which would also be another question tbh

Comment: Here is a picture, http://dharquissandas.tk/Untitled.png

Comment: @DeepHarquissandas Did you, by any chance, not instantiated the mDatabaseHelper object by using "mDatabaseHelper  = new DatabaseHelper(this);" in your acitivity.....?

Comment: I have got it to work, but it will only show a total if there is an entry in both tables. How would I show a total if there are only entries in one table and the other one is empty

Comment: Replace sum(amount) with total(amount). For sqlite, total(amount) of zero entries will return 0. Replacing sum(amount) with COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0) would work as well

Comment: This works better, but what if i would like to add decimals it does not show the full decimal it rounds to nearest number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154069/discussion-between-petul-and-deep-harquissandas).

Answer (score 0):

If both tables have same length then you can join both tables

```
 select sum(income_table.amount)-sum(expense_table.amount) from income_table inner join expense_table on expense_table.id=income_table.id;
```

Comment: If I'm not totally mistaken, this query assumes a 1 to 1 mapping of income and expense. If you insert 4 incomes and 2 expenses, the result will be the first 2 incomes minus the 2 expenses

Comment: yeah your quite right, this code  only works if both of tables have same number of rows